# HTTP error while using conda for installation of any packages

Tags: linux, http, conda, continuum

> CondaHTTPError: HTTP 000 CONNECTION FAILED for url
>   
>   onda-forge/linux-64/repodata.json> Elapsed: -
>
> An HTTP error occurred when trying to retrieve this URL. HTTP errors
>   are often intermittent, and a simple retry will get you on your way.
>
> SSLError(MaxRetryError('HTTPSConnectionPool(host=\'conda.anaconda.org\',
>   port=44                                                         3):
>   Max retries exceeded with url: /conda-forge/linux-64/repodata.json
>   (Caused b                                                         y
>   SSLError(SSLError("bad handshake: Error([(\'SSL routines\',
>   \'SSL23_GET_SERVER
>   _HELLO\', \'unknown protocol\')],)",),))',),)
>
> (tensorflow) harshvardhan@ravan:~/project$ conda info Current conda
>   install:

```
           platform : linux-64
      conda version : 4.3.30
   conda is private : False
  conda-env version : 4.3.30
conda-build version : 3.0.27
     python version : 2.7.14.final.0
   requests version : 2.18.4
   root environment : /ug/dd/harshvardhan/anaconda2  (writable)
default environment : /ug/dd/harshvardhan/anaconda2/envs/tensorflow
   envs directories : /ug/dd/harshvardhan/anaconda2/envs
                      /ug/dd/harshvardhan/.conda/envs
      package cache : /ug/dd/harshvardhan/anaconda2/pkgs
                      /ug/dd/harshvardhan/.conda/pkgs
       channel URLs : https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/main/linux-64
                      https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/main/noarch
                      https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/linux-64
                      https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/noarch
                      https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/r/linux-64
                      https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/r/noarch
                      https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/linux-64
                      https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/noarch
        config file : /ug/dd/harshvardhan/.condarc
         netrc file : None
       offline mode : False
         user-agent : conda/4.3.30 requests/2.18.4 CPython/2.7.14 Linux/3.2.0-4-amd64 debian/7.11 glibc/2.13
            UID:GID : 85090:2114
```

Can you tell me what should I do next?
I surfed other links and setting ssl_verify: False didn't work for me

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because your question is more appropriate for the StackExchange sites [**Super User**](http://superuser.com/) or [**Unix & Linux**](http://unix.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1):

I am experiencing the same issue, and am quite confident it is due to SSL/Firewall issues internally in the workplace.

Do you have proxy servers that you need to specify in your .condarc file? (.e.g)

```
proxy_servers:
    http : http://101.101.101.255:8080
    https : https://101.101.101.255:8080
```

I know it says WinXP but this still applies - https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/configuration/use-winxp-with-proxy.html

If you are specifying your organisation's servers correctly, and are still having these issues, then there is likely a firewall exception / SSL cert configuration issue that needs to be resolved, and is not a conda issue per se, but a networking problem

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try copying these files from Anaconda3/Library/bin to Anaconda3/DLLs :

libcrypto-1_1-x64.dll

libssl-1_1-x64.dll

Answer (score -1):

run these commands one by one....

```
$ export {http,https,ftp}_proxy="http://proxy-server:port"<br>
$ unset {http,https,ftp}_proxy

$ export {HTTP,HTTPS,FTP}_PROXY="http://proxy-server:port<br>
$ unset {HTTP,HTTPS,FTP}_PROXY<br>
$ source ~/.bashrc
```