# SSL Error while installing any package from conda prompt

Tags: ssl, proxy, ssl-certificate, anaconda

I use Anaconda Navigator for my machine learning experiments. Recently, I have started getting this strange SSL error no matter what I try to install using conda prompt. The error is SSL error. I am posting the error message that I get

> Solving environment: failed
>
> CondaHTTPError: HTTP 000 CONNECTION FAILED for url
>   https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free/linux-64/repodata.json.bz2
>   Elapsed: -
>
> An HTTP error occurred when trying to retrieve this URL. HTTP errors
>   are often intermittent, and a simple retry will get you on your way.
>
> If your current network has https://www.anaconda.com blocked, please
>   file a support request with your network engineering team.
>
> SSLError(MaxRetryError('HTTPSConnectionPool(host=\'repo.anaconda.com\',
>   port=443): Max retries exceeded with url:
>   /pkgs/free/linux-64/repodata.json.bz2 (Caused by
>   SSLError(SSLError("bad handshake: Error([(\'SSL routines\',
>   \'ssl3_get_server_certificate\', \'certificate verify
>   failed\')],)",),))',),)

I have an institutional proxy server; the credentials, apt.conf file etc are all OK.

Even then I am not able to install any package using conda.

Interestingly, I have installed numerous packages using conda prompt and I never faced any such error until recently. Also, I am able to follow the links (using the browser) given in the error message which means that the proxy is not blocking the site.

I was asked to use

```
conda config --set ssl_verify True
```

but even this did not help. Any help ?

I even entered the proxy server details as given in [HTTP error while using conda for installation of any packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48354258/http-error-while-using-conda-for-installation-of-any-packages)

Answer (score 31):

Try copying these files from Anaconda3/Library/bin to Anaconda3/DLLs :

libcrypto-1_1-x64.dll

libssl-1_1-x64.dll

Comment: this worked on Windows 11 on 11/21/2022

Comment: Didn't work for me on Windows 11.

Comment: Worked for me on Windows 10 in July 2023

Comment: Great, even works for Win 7

Answer (score 8):

This should do the job.

```
conda config --set ssl_verify False
```

Comment: Simple but efficient solution! Well done!

Comment: This solution opens you up to attacks, do not use it. There are alternative, secure solutions that will work.

Comment: Simply turn it back on once you are done?

Answer (score 4):

When I had an SSL error related to conda on my work laptop behind a firewall, I had to set ssl_verify to false to get it to work.

Comment: How to set it to false?

Comment: conda config --set ssl_verify False. But not work: C:\Users\gz000069>conda install -c menpo dlib
Solving environment: failed

CondaHTTPError: HTTP 000 CONNECTION FAILED for url <https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free/noarch/repodata.json.bz2>
Elapsed: -

An HTTP error occurred when trying to retrieve this URL.
HTTP errors are often intermittent, and a

Answer (score 0):

The following steps worked for me:

Use this command to see proxy_servers

```bash
conda config --show
```

This will remove saved proxy servers from anaconda configuration.

```bash
conda config --remove-key proxy_servers
```

```bash
conda clean --source-cache
```

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to .dll error

go to location where you've install anaconda3>Library>bin. search and copy following dll files

libcrypto-1_1-x64.dll
libssl-1_1-x64.dll

and paste to anaconda3>DLLs.

then restart your pc.

issue will get resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue on my corpo computer, I modified `.condarc` file to overcome this issue, this file likely located at `C:\Users\<YourUsername>\` if you can't find, run this on cmd -> `conda config --show-sources` this command will show the exact location of .condarc file. If can't see any, navigate to the [documentation](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/configuration/use-condarc.html)

If you need to add specific configurations (like proxy settings), you can add them to this file. For instance:

```
proxy_servers:
  http: http://your_proxy_server:your_proxy_port
  https: https://your_proxy_server:your_proxy_port
```

I changed my solver `solver=classic`, made `ssl_verify=false` (i don't recommend this, keep true if possible) also deleted predefined proxy paths and left `http` & `https` empty. In the end my`.condarc` file looks like :

```
proxy_servers:
  http: 
  https: 
ssl_verify: false
solver: classic
```

Answer (score 0):

**anaconda3>Library>bin**

Search and copy following dll files:

**libcrypto-1_1-x64.dll
libssl-1_1-x64.dll**

and paste to **anaconda3>DLLs**.

then restart your PC

issue will get resolved:)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).