# Anaconda package install error [WinError 126] The specified module could not be found

Tags: python, anaconda, package

I'm trying to install packages from anaconda command prompt but I couldn't install any package to any environment including root environment. For example I'm trying to install tensorflow by the command:

`conda install tensorflow`

but I'm getting this error:

`[WinError 126] The specified module could not be found`

Tensorflow is just an example, I'm getting this error for every package. But I could install packages from normal command prompt by the command: 
`pip install tensorflow`

Last thing that I need to mention that before I faced with this problem I face with 
`CondaHTTPError SSLError(MaxRetryError` while creating new environment or opening jupyter notebook or installing packages. I mean I firstly solve this problem to doing anything. I solved it by https://stackoverflow.com/a/56103137/2364340 . So I'm not sure is that solution cause of that new problem. However, I compulsorily did it because otherwise I even not create a environment or opening jupyter notebook. But it is not enough as without packages I couldn't keep walking.

I am using Python 3.7.4 (Anaconda3) on Windows 10 (64-bit). I also installed PyCharm Community Edition 2019.3

Please help

Comment: Can you share the entire output you receive from `conda install tensorflow`? The advice I usually give when dealing with issues like these is simply to remove all traces of Anaconda and start from scratch.

Comment: Yes, I did it. Here is the output( short version as it is too long): `conda install tensorflow
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: done
==>WARNING: A newer version of conda exists.<==
  current version: 4.7.12
  latest version: 4.8.2
Please update conda by running
 $ conda update -n base -c defaults conda
 added / updated specs:
    - tensorflow
The following packages will be downloaded:
    tensorflow-2.0.0
Proceed ([y]/n)? y
Downloading and Extracting Packages
tensorflow-estimator| 250 KB|0%
[WinError 126] Belirtilen modül bulunamadı`

Comment: So you’re not getting that error anymore?