# Pre-commit install-hooks does not work (SSLError)

Tags: python, ssl, pre-commit-hook, pre-commit, pre-commit.com

I use conda Python environments. Whenever I try to run `pre-commit install-hooks`, I get the error

```
 Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/ruamel-yaml/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded w
ith url: /simple/ruamel-yaml/ (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")) - skipping

...

WARNING: pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.
```

However, `pip` works just fine when I use it.

I already tried `pre-commit clean`, uninstalling `pre-commit` and reinstalling it (either with `conda` or `pip`), updating `pip`, switching off the VPN, and also any other solution I could find on Google. Nothing seems to work. Could you please help me?

The `.pre-commit-config.yaml` looks like this:

```
repos:
-   repo: https://github.com/pre-commit/pre-commit-hooks
    rev: v3.2.0
    hooks:
    -   id: check-yaml
    -   id: check-added-large-files
-   repo: https://github.com/psf/black
    rev: stable
    hooks:
    - id: black
      language_version: python3.8
-   repo: https://github.com/pycqa/isort
    rev: 5.10.1
    hooks:
      - id: isort
        name: isort (python)
```

Comment: your python is broken -- nothing stackoverflow can help you with

Comment: Install `pre-commit` using `pipx` which will create a separate Python install and its own virtualenv.

Comment: @anthonysottile That's not very helpful...

Comment: @PatrickMevzek I tried it, doesn't work unfortunately :(

Comment: @karu reinstall python is about all we can tell you -- but that doesn't have a place on SO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following helped me:

- uninstall pre-commit (via pip/conda)
- delete the pre-commit.exe (found by "where pre-commit"). That's crucial; otherwise it still uses this exe even though pre-commit is installed in the conda env, and I still got the same error
- install pre-commit via conda; pip doesn't work because it still looks for the exe

Answer (score 2):

Anaconda environment is broken, not only on pre-commit, but every operation which uses SSL module.

Solution:

> copying these files from Anaconda3/Library/bin to Anaconda3/DLLs :
>
> libcrypto-{version}-x64.dll
>
> libssl-{version}-x64.dll

Reference: [SSL Error while installing any package from conda prompt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51892938/ssl-error-while-installing-any-package-from-conda-prompt)